# WordPress Multisite Multiple child theme

Tags: multisite, child-theme

I have a mulisite setup and I am using one theme for multiple sites in it and each site have a custom layout and design. So for that I need to create a child-theme. But I don't know how to create multiple child theme for each site so I can add customization in each child theme style.css, footer.php, function.php, header.php

e.g

I am using theme canvas for all sites. 
then I created canvas-child and customized it for site1 now I need to customize it for other site2 then how I can create one more child theme with current main theme canvas to effect customization on site2.

Comment: You want to create a child of a child of a child theme?

Comment: Or are you asking how to make a theme with many children?

Comment: I am asking for theme with many children

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy your `canvas-child` folder and call it `canvas-child-2`, or similar. Then open up `style.css` in `canvas-child-2`, and edit the `Theme Name:`. Do this for as many different child themes you need.

You will then need to enable the child themes for the sites you wish to use them on. Visit the *Sites* menu in your Network Dashboard, and click the edit link under one of the sites. Switch to the **Themes** tab and click on the **Enable** link under the name of the theme you wish to use on this site. Do this for all sites you wish to use a custom child theme on.

The final step is to activate the themes on the sites. Login to the site's administration dashboard and visit the *Themes* menu. Click on the **Activate** link under the child theme you wish to use on this site. Do this for all sites you wish to use a custom child theme on.

Comment: @bunjeshea Many Thanks for your answer and its exactly what i am looking for. I cannot give you repu or accept answer because of account restrictions.

Comment: The naming convention kind of sucks. If you wanted to map each child theme to a specific site. My advice would be to name the child theme directory like `canvas-child-<site-id-here>`. Then in your `style.css` set the `Theme Name: Specific Site Name Here`. From a file directory standpoint, the child themes are easy to locate and map. From a WordPress GUI standpoint, the child themes are quick and easy to identify for enabling/disabling, etc. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @MichaelEcklund I agree that `{theme}-child-{number}` isn't a very good naming convention. It's only an example though, I would definitely encourage coming up with a much better one which fits the circumstances!