# Separated Theme file on multi site network in subdomain

Tags: multisite

thanks in advance to all.

I'v just enabled multi site on my domain with the `sub domain` option.

I was wondering if there is an option to overwrite specific page templates only in the sub domain site Iv created ? I'v couldn't find any folders or files that only associated just with the sub domain.

thanks in advance to all,

Answer (score 0):

No, the template hierarchy does not contain Site specific templates.

Instead, consider using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), allowing you to override a template specifically in that child theme, yet still use the parent/base themes templates for everything else

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sorry, but I'm not sure I understood. like creating a site without multi site option ?

Comment: Create a child theme for each site, and activate the child theme. I strongly recommend researching what child themes are. My answer has nothing to do with creating content or sites

Comment: thanks man , that's what I was looking for , the problem is I'm when `multisite network` is enabled where should I create those folders ? on the word press dashboard the virtual sub domain created by word press has a child theme, but its virtual its working with the same theme as the parent. in cPanel there is no separated folder for my subdomain, hope I'm clear haha

Comment: I have found an answer or rather the right q I had to ask https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81886/wordpress-multisite-multiple-child-theme

thanks anyways bro appreciate

Comment: @Osh the `wp-content` folder works exactly the same way under a multisite as it does under a single site, everything goes in the same place it always did. If you're looking for a site specific folder, you won't find it because there is none, that's not how multisite works.